How do I generate a top 3 values from columns of a data sheet in Excel?
I have a large data sheet in Excel (sheet1) with columns C, D, E, and F containing time (12:00), location (New York), surname (Smith), and first name (John) data, respectively. Example data:



Time
Location
Surname
First name




1
12:00
New York
Smith


2
12:00
London
Smith


3
13:30
Paris
Jones


4
12:00
New York
Smith


5
13:30
New York
Abbott


6
16:30
Paris
Jones



On a separate sheet (sheet2) I would like to generate a top 3 table of the values in these columns - that is, the table shows the 3 most common values that appear in each of the above columns, as follows:



Time
Location
Surname
First name




1
12:00
New York
Smith


2
13:30
Paris
Jones


3
16:30
London
Abbott



Note that the columns are treated completely separately, so the 'time' displaying next to 1 should be the time that occurs most frequently in the sheet1 column for time, the 'Location' displaying next to 1 should be the most frequent location, and so on.
I am using the below formula, which successfully generates the most column value:
=index(sheet1!C2:C999,match(max(countif(sheet1!C2:C999,sheet1!C2:C999)),countif(sheet1!C2:C999,sheet1!C2:C999),0))

How to generate a top 3 instead? Please note that although I am using Excel 365, i would like the formula to be able to work with older versions of excel too.
Many thanks in advance!

What do you mean by top 3 values? Do you mean first 3 rows? If so then try =TAKE(C2:F999,3).

Apologies - I mean the three most commonly occurring values in the columns. E.g., if New York happens to occur 69 times, London 65 times, and Paris 62 times, the result would be New York, London, and Paris in (for example) cells A2, A3, and A4 on sheet2

Please post few sample data to your post as text table so that we can copy those. Mention your version of Excel. Is it Excel-365?

If your formula returns the most frequent value in the column, you're probably looking for the "Top 3 Most Frequent Values in a Column".

Saying you have a large datasheet: how to handle same frequencies?

Probably a duplicate of a newer question linked to an older question with a lot of linked questions (some closed as duplicates).

In Sheet2 use the following formula-
=LET(loc,Sheet1!C2:C13,TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(UNIQUE(loc),COUNTIFS(loc,UNIQUE(loc))),2,-1),3,1))



If you plan on using O365 anyway, you could spill it in one go:
=LET(data,A2:D7,MAKEARRAY(3,COLUMNS(data),LAMBDA(r,c,LET(i,INDEX(data,,c),x,XMATCH(i,i),f,FREQUENCY(x,x),INDEX(SORTBY(i,DROP(f,-1),-1),r)))))
If you intend to use older Excel (as commented), you could make use of the following dragged to the right and down:
=INDEX(A$2:A$999,MATCH(LARGE(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A$2:A$999,A$2:A$999,),MATCH(A$2:A$999,A$2:A$999,)),ROW(A1)),FREQUENCY(MATCH(A$2:A$999,A$2:A$999,),MATCH(A$2:A$999,A$2:A$999,)),0))

